# How to model custom request params in Spring for JSON API?

Tags: spring, json-api

I'm currently trying to model out the query parameter structure of [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) and work it into my Spring Boot project.  I'm going to focus on [filters](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering), sorting, pagination, and maybe field restriction.

I want to start with filtering first, so I'd like my REST endpoints to be able to handle JSON-API style URL requests like

```
GET /comments?filter[post]=1 HTTP/1.1

GET /comments?filter[post]=1,2 HTTP/1.1

GET /comments?filter[post]=1,2&filter[author]=12 HTTP/1.1
```

My plan is capture all JSON API specific query parameters in a top-level `JsonApiParams` object like:

```
public class JsonApiParams {
  private Filters filters;
  private Sorting sorting;
  private Paging paging;

  // getters, setters
}
```

And then model out `Filters`, `Sorting`, `Paging` as well.  This `JsonApiParams` object will then be accepted as a request param in my `@RestController` endpoints like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/v1/{entity}"},
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {"application/vnd.api+json"})
@ResponseBody
public JsonApiTopLevel jsonApiGetByEntity(@PathVariable String entity, JsonApiParams params) {
  // convert params to DB query
}
```

So, how should I model my `JsonApiParams` object to be able to handle requests like the ones above (e.g. `/comments?filter[post]=1,2&filter[author]=12`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, Spring out-of-the-box uses the bracket notation for Maps.  I was able to format my URL query params like this `/comments?filter[post]=1,2&filter[author]=12` with the following model:

```
public class JsonApiParams {
    private Map<String, List<String>> filter;
    private List<String> sort;
    private Map<JsonApiPaginationKeys, Integer> page;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Then, in my case, I converted the filters to a [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) `Predicate`, and the `sort` and `page` fields into a Spring `Pageable` request.  Easy conversion and worked seamlessly.

Comment: Hi Heez, could you please you elaborate a little bit more? Not sure how to use it on @RequestParam